# How to use encryption when calling getDocument from the DocuSign Rest API

Tags: rest, docusignapi, docusignconnect

I need to encrypt documents when downloading them using the getDocument method in Java. When I set the "encrypt" Document Option to "true" as a parameter, I get an exception that no security appliance is configured?

I could not understand what that exactly means.

EnvelopesApi.GetDocumentOptions options = envelopesApi.new GetDocumentOptions();
options.setEncrypt("true");
byte[] results = envelopesApi.getDocument(this.accountId, envelopeId, "combined",options);

The exception comes as: "errorCode": "NO_SECURITY_APPLIANCES_CONFIGURED"

Comment: All API calls are made using SSL/TLS and so any call, including getDocument is already encrypted. If you're worried about security - you're covered. Is there another reason you need encryption ?

Answer (score 0):

More info on the Security Appliance is available here: https://www.docusign.com/products/hybrid-cloud-appliances

When using a Security Appliance, you hold access to the encryption keys used to secure your documents. Without a Security Appliance, the GetDocuments `encrypt` option has no function.

As Inbar states, your API call is already protected by SSL/TLS.